# Unlink MAPLE symbolic from Matlab

Tags: matlab, maple

When I installed MAPLE I synchronized it with my MATLAB account. My MAPLE license has expired and I am unable to do regular symbolic math in MATLAB. I just tried to define a symbolic character in MATLAB and I got this error:

```
syms k

??? Error using ==> sym.sym at 198 
Error using ==> maplemex 
Feature has expired. 
Feature:       Maple17 
Expire date:   09-jan-2015
```

... and so on. Can someone please help me unlink MAPLE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, uninstalling Maple will also remove the Maple toolbox for Matlab. You can also uninstall just the Maple toolbox for Matlab from the Programs and Features menu in the Control Panel.

For Linux, to remove just the toolbox, there is an uninstall script in the root of the Matlab install directory in a folder called Uninstall_MapleToolbox.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is:

```
...\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@mupad
```

and from this directory, run the m-file called `mupad.m`, 
and your symbolic math toolbox works fine.

This resolves the problem for once and you would need to run this file everytime when you need the `toolbox- mupad`.